# Find the next Wednesday

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to display the date of the first upcoming Wednesday, to show the start time of a weekly event.

If it's Sunday 15/12/2019 then it would return Wednesday 18/12/2019.

If it's Monday 16/12/2019 then it would return Wednesday 18/12/2019.

If it's Wednesday 18/12/2019 then it would return Wednesday 25/12/2019.

I tried this function:

```
=TODAY()+(7-(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)-2))
```

*(To test, I replaced TODAY() with A1 where A1 is a custom date: `=A1+(7-(WEEKDAY(A1,3)-2))`)*

but on Mondays and Tuesdays, it returns next week's Wednesday, rather than this week's.

So I solved it like this:

```
=IF((WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)-2)<0, TODAY()-(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)-2), TODAY()+(7-(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)-2)))
```

*(Test function: `=IF((WEEKDAY(A1,3)-2)<0, A1-(WEEKDAY(A1,3)-2), A1+(7-(WEEKDAY(A1,3)-2)))`)*

but this leaves me with a big chunky IF-function.

Since I am trying to keep the date as a variable to use in more complicated formulas, is there no way to more easily adjust the first function, without using complicated IFs?

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
= A1 + 8 - WEEKDAY(A1 + 4)
```

Assuming you don't want to use `if` statements.

Answer (score 2):

```
=A1+8-WEEKDAY(A1-3)
```

**Algorithm**

- Add one week + one day to the original date so we start with a week later
- Subtract the Weekday number of the weekday we are interested in

  - For this purpose, instead of `8` we use `MOD(8,7)` although we could use 8
  - Weekday(Wednesday) = 4
  - So `8-4` --`1-4` --> `-3`

[image]

```
=A1+8-WEEKDAY(A1+4)
```

Would also work in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

There are already two very useful answers but here's one more alternative which simply uses the `return_type` parameter:

`=A1+8-WEEKDAY(A1,13)`

13 = Numbers 1 (Wednesday) through 7 (Tuesday)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(FILTER(ROW(INDIRECT(VALUE(TODAY()+6)&":"&VALUE(TODAY()))), 
 TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(VALUE(TODAY()+6)&":"&VALUE(TODAY()))), "ddd")="WED")))
```

where true ArrayFormula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_DATE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, 
 IFNA(A2:A+ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A2:A)+1))^0*COLUMN(A:G)^1)), " "))), 
 "where dayofweek(Col1) = 4", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

or shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(ROW(A1:A6)+TODAY(), 
 "where dayofweek(Col1)=4"))
```

[image: 0]

---

or shorter arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A3:A5+8-WEEKDAY(A3:A5-3))
```

[image: 0]